# Can't install TA-LIB?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, spyder, ta-lib

I'm using Spyder 4.0.1 and Python 3.7 and trying to:

pip install ta-lib

however, after a few cmdwindows pop open and auto-close very quickly at the beginning, nothing seems to be happening and the iPython console is just stick on "pip install ta-lib" with no new In[]: box showing.

I have tried manually stopping and restarting the kernel and then retrying but the same thing happens.  Can someone help troubleshoot?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which OS you are using, but in MacOS what I did was:

1) Installed `ta-lib` using brew.

`brew install ta-lib`

2) Then Ran the `pip install TA-Lib` command.

The above step should work in most of the cases, but one of my friend was facing some issue with `gcc`, if you are facing any issue related to `gcc`, try installing `gcc`. For installing `gcc` you can use the command: 
`brew install gcc`

Hope this helps.